# Swift: how to willSet object's attribute directly?

Tags: ios, macos, swift

Here's the code from Apple's Doc:

```
class NameShape{
    var numberOfSide: Int = 0
    var name:String
    func simpleDescription() -> String {
        return "A square with \(numberOfSide) sides."
    }
    init (name: String){
        self.name = name
        }
}

class Square:NameShape{
    var sideLength: Double
    init(name: String, sideLength: Double){
        self.sideLength = sideLength
        super.init(name: name)


        numberOfSide = 4
    }

    func area() ->Double {
        return sideLength * sideLength
    }

    override func simpleDescription() -> String {
        return "A square with sides of length \(sideLength)."
    }

}

class EquilateralTriangle:NameShape{
    var sideLength: Double = 0.0

    init(sideLength: Double, name: String){
        self.sideLength = sideLength
        super.init(name: name)
        numberOfSide = 3
    }

    var perimeter: Double{
    get{
        return 3.0 * sideLength
    }
    set{
        sideLength = newValue / 3.0
    }
    }

    override func simpleDescription() -> String {
        return "An equilateral triangle with sides of length \(sideLength)."
    }
}

class TriangleAndSquare{
    var triangle:EquilateralTriangle{
    willSet {
    square.sideLength = newValue.sideLength
    }
    }
    var square: Square{
    willSet {
        triangle.sideLength = newValue.sideLength
    }
    }
    init(size: Double, name: String){
        square = Square(name: name, sideLength: size)
        triangle = EquilateralTriangle(sideLength: size, name: name)
    }
}
```

if I follow the Doc,

```
var triangleAndSquare = TriangleAndSquare(size: 10, name: "another test shape")
triangleAndSquare.square.sideLength //10.0
triangleAndSquare.triangle.sideLength //10.0
triangleAndSquare.square = Square(name: "larger square", sideLength: 50)
triangleAndSquare.triangle.sideLength //500.0
```

but if I just change `triangle.sideLength`:

```
triangleAndSquare.triangle.sideLength = 25
triangleAndSquare.triangle.sideLength //25.0
```

but the `square.sideLength` is not `willSet`ed:

```
triangleAndSquare.square.sideLength //50.0
```

Seems the `willSet` needs to tie to `triangle` or `square`, because `square.sideLength = newValue.sideLength`

How can I make the change of attribute of `triangle` directly only if I set the `square`'s attribute, but not creating a new `Square` object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not working as you expect because `willSet` & co. act on the actual property (in this case `triangle` & `square`) changing. As they are classes, modifying their properties doesn't change the class pointer that represents them, only what its contents in turn point at (i.e. it's the same triangle & square, not new instances).

To do what you want, you will have to subclass the classes `Square` & `Triangle` to provide the `willSet` inside those subclasses on the properties you want to observe. To make it work as you expect, each of those subclasses will have to have a new property (say `brother: NameShape` ) which you will have to set in the compound class's `init`, so that they can change each other's properties.